# CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent with Custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have two lists, I want to check whether the two lists are the same ( order not important), and whether it's the same depends on the `IEqualityComparer` instance I implement.

The ideal case is that I can use `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` with Custom `IEqualityComparer`. However it seems that `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` doesn't take in any `IEqualityComparer`.

Any idea on how to do this in a succinct and reusable manner?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` is implemented as:

```
Assert.That(actual, new CollectionEquivalentConstraint(expected), message, args);
```

You can write out your assert that way and supply a custom `IEqualityComparer` with `Using`:

```
Assert.That(actual,
    new CollectionEquivalentConstraint(expected).Using(customComparer));
```

You can also shorten `new CollectionEquivalentConstraint` to `Is.EquivalentTo`:

```
Assert.That(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected).Using(customComparer));
```